# Pandas is splitting a strings across rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

```
       POS APLICAÇÃO             NOMECLATURA     UOM
0   340.0   Trens -      PLATE, INSTRUCTION  Unidad
1     NaN    ERJ145                     NaN       e
2   773.0   Trens -   PLACARD (O P/N- 2309-  Unidad
3     NaN    ERJ145  2036-501 NÃO SUBSTITUI       e
4     NaN       NaN   O P/N- PNE104003-027)     NaN
5   795.0   Trens -                    BOLT    Cada
6     NaN    ERJ145                     NaN     NaN
7   771.0   Trens -               NAMEPLATE    Cada
8     NaN    ERJ145                     NaN     NaN
9   610.0   Trens -             RSA SCRAPER    Cada
10    NaN    ERJ145                     NaN     NaN
11  425.0   Trens -         UPPER SECONDARY    Cada
12    NaN    ERJ145          STRUT ASSEMBLY     NaN
13  336.0   Trens -                  SPRING    Cada
14    NaN    ERJ145                     NaN     NaN
15  408.0   Trens -         BEARING, SEALED    Cada
16    NaN    ERJ145                     NaN     NaN


[17 rows x 14 columns]
```

[table in the pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3RDL.png)

I have this data frame and my problem is simple. The 0 line should be "Trens - ERJ145", but the "ERJ145" only apeears at line 1, and the 2 line should concatenate the line 3 and 4. Basically, I need to concatenate every String that apeears below a row that have a PO.

Comment: How do you generate this DataFrame? It might be better to fix this upstream

Comment: it's reading a pdf using tabula.

Comment: What about the rows with only NaNs? These don't have anything to concatenate with

Comment: in the pdf they are one row, but part of the text is in the line below, it only happens with two columns, so tabula read that as different rows.

Comment: added a print of the table inside the pdf to clarify.

Comment: Any breakline in "Nomenclature" column like in "Applied on" one?

Comment: yes, and in UOM as well

Comment: I was thinking of iterating through the DataFrame and concatenating all rows if the POS column in empty, but i dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

**updated according to your comments**

Given part or your example: (*but will work for your entire dataframe)*

| index | POS | APLICAÇÃO | NOMECLATURA | UOM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 340.0 | Trens - | PLATE, INSTRUCTION | Unidad |
| 1 | 340.0 | ERJ145 | NaN | e |
| 2 | 773.0 | Trens - | PLACARD (O P/N- 2309- | Unidad |
| 3 | 773.0 | ERJ145 | 2036-501 NÃO SUBSTITUI | e |
| 4 | 773.0 | NaN | O P/N- PNE104003-027) | NaN |

Apply the following code:

```
#.ffil() (*forward fill*) the NaN values of POS column to be able to group them together in the next step
df.POS = df.POS.ffill()

#groupy all the lines by POS and then .sum() their content
df.groupby('POS').sum().reset_index()
```

Output:

| index | POS | APLICAÇÃO | NOMECLATURA | UOM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 340.0 | Trens -ERJ145 | PLATE, INSTRUCTION | Unidade |
| 1 | 773.0 | Trens -ERJ145 | PLACARD (O P/N- 2309-2036-501 NÃO SUBSTITUIO P/N- PNE104003-027) | Unidade |

Comment: it worked with APLICAÇÃO because in that example, all rows of that columns have information in the row bellow, but in the NOMECLATURE column, it returns NaN if the row bellow is NaN.

Comment: changed the table on my question to include all columns that is being split.

Comment: sorry for the delay, I had already given up, but you nailed it! thank you very much!